# Is there any limitation for http outbound gateway with large payload size

Tags: spring-integration, httpclient

We use Spring Integration in our SpringBoot project to get http response from our customer and then transform the payload to our system needed, however we found that when the payload size is over (around) 11M, the http request will always timeout (we set 10 minutes for timeout), but we can use CURL or postman to download 11M payload successfully within 5 minutes.

May I know is there any default setting in Spring Integration or HTTP client for the payload size which lead to timeout?

Currently we setup a alert to monitor such case and will manually download the payload by postman, but this is not a good solution.

Comment: It looks like you has http request timeout setting instead of payload size limit.

Comment: yes, the timeout setting is 10 mins, however we can >11M payload by using Postman within 5 mins, however, the request will timeout even we change time out setting to 30 minutes, we didn't get problems when payload size <10M

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Gateway is fully based on the `RestTemplate` from Spring MVC which can be supplied with one of the `ClientHttpRequestFactory`. By default it is a `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. Consider to inject a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and tweak its `HttpClient` respectively to your task.